# How to Turn Navbar Collapse into Sidebar in Mobile View using Reactstrap in React.js?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, navbar, reactstrap

**Referring to the image links in the comments below**, do you know how to achieve the effects which turn navbar collapse into sidebar properly in mobile view? How to achieve it without affecting and shifting the logo and the button?

```
//[Home Navbar Desktop View]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THf6k.jpg 
//[Home Navbar Mobile View]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiJOc.png
//[Home Navbar/Sidebar Extend Mobile View]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhJxQ.png

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./components/home/home";
import About from "./components/about/about";
import Portfolio from "./components/portfolio/portfolio";
import Services from "./components/services/services";
import { Collapse, Navbar, NavbarToggler, NavbarBrand, Nav, NavItem, NavLink, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import './App.css';
import 'tachyons';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className='App'>
        <Navbar className='sticky-top' color="light" light expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/"><b className='logo'>Amecle</b></NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler className="order-first" onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/about">About</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/services">Services</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/portfolio">Portfolio</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
          <Button className="still_on_view" outline color="primary">Request a quote</Button>{' '}
        </Navbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer work for me.

At `<Navbar className='sticky-top' color="light" light expand="md">`
change `expand="md"` to `expand="lg"` (this indicate when media at max 1024px (ipad size), will collapse).

Comment: This only affects when it will collapse. The problem is how to change the navbar collapse into a sidebar?